# Taking specific dates from database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database table

my code inserts a row here everytime user solves a question.

```
CREATE TABLE `u_s_q` (
  `ID` int(8) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `questionid` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `u_s_q`
-- 

INSERT INTO `u_s_q` VALUES (1, 1, 2, '2011-11-26 14:02:14');
INSERT INTO `u_s_q` VALUES (2, 1, 5, '2011-11-26 14:24:32');
```

like this.

I am trying to see the question id's that user with the id = "1" solved in the month of november.

I don't know how to write that SQL statement

How do I write that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MONTH(time)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) to return the month number, and query for 11 (November)

```
SELECT questionid FROM u_s_q 
WHERE
  userid = 1
  AND MONTH(`time`) = 11
```

Alternatively, use `MONTHNAME()` to get the actual word "November", or whatever it would be called in your locale

```
SELECT questionid FROM u_s_q 
WHERE
  userid = 1
  AND MONTHNAME(`time`) = 'November'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll check your answer when stackoverflow allows me :)

Comment: Type of the `time` column is a `timestamp`, does MONTH() function would be able to handle this type?

Comment: @Sil Yes, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP are stored in the same format yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss, and will both work correctly with `MONTH()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the month function:

```
SELECT questionid
FROM u_s_q
WHERE userid = 1 AND month(time) = 11;
```